# Change default s.w.org dns-prefetch resource hint value

Tags: wp-head

By default, [wp_resource_hints()](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/06/resource-hints-in-4-6/) prints hints for `s.w.org`, I am trying to change the default printed value. I am not trying to get rid of the hook, I indeed need it and want to use it, however witout `s.w.org`.

```
function resource_hints( $hints, $relation_type ) {
    if ( 'dns-prefetch' === $relation_type ) {
        $key = array_search( '//s.w.org', $hints, true );
        if ( false !== $key ) {
                unset( $hints[ $key ] );
        }
        $hints[] = 'http://make.wordpress.org';

    } elseif ( 'prerender' === $relation_type ) {
            $hints[] = 'https://make.wordpress.org/great-again';
    }
    return $hints;
}
add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'resource_hints', 999, 2 );
```

The function works for adding values for `dns-prefetch`, `preconnect`, `prefetch`, and `prerender`, however I cannot get rid or edit the first `s.w.org` resource hint. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 2):

```
var_export( $hints );
```

gave me

```
array (
  0 => 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/',
)
```

so that means the array key is not `s.w.org` but `https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/`.

Changing the function and using the key of the array with the full url did remove the s.w.org hint while still letting me use resource hints.

```
function resource_hints( $hints, $relation_type ) {
    if ( 'dns-prefetch' === $relation_type ) {
        // Export the value of the $hints variable
        // to see what is inside of it.
        var_export( $hints );

        // Knowing that the url is not s.w.org but
        // 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/'
        // I can search for it in the array
        $key = array_search( 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/', $hints, true );
        if ( false !== $key ) {

                // and here I can unset this key
                unset( $hints[ $key ] );
        }

        // while I can add custom, site specific hints here
        $hints[] = 'http://make.wordpress.org';

    } elseif ( 'prerender' === $relation_type ) {
            $hints[] = 'https://make.wordpress.org/great-again';
    }
    return $hints;
}
add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'resource_hints', 999, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

This worked for me

```
/* Add anothers dns-prefetches */
function makewp_example_resource_hints( $hints, $relation_type ) {
  if ( 'dns-prefetch' === $relation_type ) {
    $hints[] = '//something.com';
    $hints[] = '//something.net';
    $hints[] = '//something.org';
  }

  return $hints;
}
add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'makewp_example_resource_hints', 10, 2 );
/* Remove s.w.org dns-prefetch */
add_filter( 'emoji_svg_url', '__return_false' );
```